# AWS IAM CustomPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have created a custom managed AWS IAM policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1567509959500",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByFastForward",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesBySquash",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByThreeWay",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestBySquash",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByThreeWay",
                "codecommit:PutFile"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:420843264582:ui-repos",
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:420843264582:API-repos"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "codecommit:References": "refs/heads/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But any user on which this policy is applied is getting 403 when Git pushes to any branch.

> I want users to create branches, allow all operations on other branches except the master branch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the whole thing (you put the json inside the question really - why external link?), then you only have a deny statement and nothing to grant your users any rights to codecommit.